# how to call second superclass methods from subclass in java

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

```
class A
{
  public void display()
  {
    System.out.println("Class A display!!!");
  }
}

class B extends A
{
  public void display()
  {
    System.out.println("Class B display!!!");
  }
}

class C extends B
{
  public void display()
  {
    System.out.println("Class C display!!!");
    super.display(); // will call B's display() method
    // how to call A's display() method here?
  }
}


public static void main(String args[])
{
  C obj = new C();
  obj.display(); // will call C's display() method
}

}
```

How can I call `A`'s `display()` method from `C`'s `display()` method? Is it possible to somehow call `A`'s `display()` method using `super`?

Comment: You can't. A class is only aware of its direct parent.

Comment: No, it's not possible; although you could add an extra method in somewhere to call it.

Comment: Thanks, @BoristheSpider.  I knew Jon Skeet had written an excellent answer to this question somewhere; I just wasn't sure how to find it.